# How can I asynchronously update a featureLayer?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, mapbox

I'm trying to dynamically change a marker layer on my map without requiring that my user reload the page. When users first visit my page they will see a map with some markers representing various locations. I want the user to be able to click a button and have the marker layer change - asynchronously. For example, when they first visit the page it will show them a list of restaurants, but when they click on the "coffee" button, then the marker layer for coffee shops will replace the restaurants marker layer. I have something like the following load when the user first visits my page (it works fine):

```
var features = [{
    type: 'Feature',
    properties: {
        description: "A Place",
        'marker-size': 'large' 
    },
    geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [74.12345, 35.12345]
    }
    ...
}];
var geoJson = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: features
};
var geocoder = L.mapbox.geocoder('myname.12345'),
    map = L.mapbox.map('map', ''myname.12345')
    geocoder.query("New York, NY", showMap);
    function showMap(err, data) {
        map.fitBounds(data.lbounds);
    }
    map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
```

The function below is supposed to change the featureLayer on my map, but it doesn't work. That is, nothing happens when this function is triggered. What am I doing wrong?

```
<button type="button" onclick="showNewFeatureLayer()">Coffee Shops</button>
<div id="map"></div> // contains the MapBox map

function showNewFeatureLayer() {
    var features = [{
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {
            description: "Another Place",
            'marker-size': 'large' 
        },
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [74.23456, 35.23456]
        }
        ...
    }];
    var geoJson = {
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: features
    };
    map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
}
```

I suspect it may have to do with the fact that MapBox renders the map in an iFrame. However, I've seen other sites asynchronously show different featureLayers, so I know it's possible. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: As an improvement I'd recommend you to:
1) Store the geocoded LatLng data. Each geocoder has a query limit, and often the coordinates won't change.
2) Store each data received by your async in a FeatureGroup/LayerGroup. When users change back (e.g. back from coffee to restaurants) you don't have to reload all data, but just change displayed layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect it may have to do with the fact that MapBox renders the map in an iFrame.

So there are two ways to embed maps with Mapbox: if you want to do something like this, using Mapbox.js, you shouldn't go the iframe route, or what we call 'embeds': you should copy the full code of an example and instantiate your map in a `<div>` element. From the code you've posted, you're almost there - you would just need to create `<div id='map'></div>` on your page and CSS to make it a size - you can copy both of these from [the simple map example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/).

There's also an issue with the line:

```
map = L.mapbox.map('map', ''myname.12345')
```

There are two `'`s before `myname`, and that'll break the code. To catch errors like that, you'll want to enable [browser debugging tools](http://debugbrowser.com).